# Is there a bare metal provider that permits blockchain login?

Tags: metamask, authentication, vps

I would like to rent a bare metal server (such as Vultr or Scaleway), pay in crypto, and also not make an account with email but authentication somehow via the blockchain.

I know MetaMask can be used for log ins, but I am wondering if there may be an even simpler way. Perhaps your cryptocurrency password would be used to access the bare metal, so whoever paid for it would be the only person who could have in?

In either case, is there any way to get bare metal only with blockchain to pay, authenticate and use?

Comment: so an unlockable keyed entrance to a server locker by Metamask signature request log-in?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to rent a bare metal server (such as Vultr or Scaleway), pay in crypto, and also not make an account with email but authentication somehow via the blockchain.

There is no such provider.

Creating non-authenticated setup attracts a lot of bad actors, like any anonymous services (think Tor, etc.). Bad actors lower the quality of the network and IPs of the server provider. Having a low quality IP means your data center is booted off the network. Providing this kind of service is not viable for any commercial, rational, actor.

Credit/debit card payments work as weak authentication. Just get a crypto debit card and use it.